# Why does strcpy() not work accept string as argument?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to write a little personal Planner App, and want store information in a class Tasks,

nothing to fancy yet but strcpy does not recognize the string c_task; 
compiler say c:tastk is std:string Tasks::c_task so I understand that it is not the right argument for strcpy. So the question is how to make strcpy accept that string ?

```
  class Tasks {
public:
    string c_task = "";
    int date;
    int category;
    int priority;

    void newTask(string n_task);
};

void Tasks::newTask(string n_task)
{
    strcpy_s(c_task, n_task);



}
```

Comment: Because `strcpy` is a C function, taking `char*` as parameters, no need for it when you have objects: `c_task = std::move(n_task);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::string` related functions. `strcpy_s` acts upon `char *` not on `std::string`.

```
class Tasks {
public:
    std::string c_task = "";
    int date;
    int category;
    int priority;

    void newTask(std::string n_task);
};

void Tasks::newTask(std::string n_task)
{
    c_task = std::move(n_task);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strcpy is a standard library function for C language.You should use copy constructor of string.

Comment: In the code in the question, `strcpy_s` should be replaced by the **assignment** operator, not the copy constructor. The target object has already been constructed.